# Is there an alternative for vnstat network traffic monitor?

Tags: network-monitoring, vnstat

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 my USB modem's interface name **changed from wwan0 to wwx001e101f0000**. I do not mind that and also read this has some good reasons. Unfortunately **vnstat stopped working for this interface**:

```
$ vnstat -i wwx001e101f0000
Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/wwx001e101f0000": No such file or directory
```

It works properly for ethernet interface enp4s0:

```
$ vnstat 
Database updated: Wed Aug 29 09:09:11 2018

   enp4s0 since 08/15/2018

          rx:  24.93 GiB      tx:  10.19 GiB      total:  35.12 GiB

   monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       Aug '18     24.93 GiB |   10.19 GiB |   35.12 GiB |  123.21 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated     27.27 GiB |   11.15 GiB |   38.42 GiB |

   daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     yesterday     16.45 GiB |    2.26 GiB |   18.71 GiB |    1.86 Mbit/s
         today    107.07 MiB |  473.64 MiB |  580.71 MiB |  147.83 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated       280 MiB |    1.21 GiB |    1.48 GiB |
```

I would need some alternative to measure consumed data as I use this modem with limited amount of data available (LTE modem). Is there any alternative? I found just a lot of tools which offers real time traffic monitoring, but I need the historical data.

Answer (score 1):

I realized vnstat will work properly even for interface wwx001e101f0000 but I had to do this:

```
sudo vnstat -u -i wwx001e101f0000
Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/wwx001e101f0000": No such file or directory
Info: -> A new database has been created.
```

And then set this in /etc/vnstat.conf

```
# default interface
Interface "wwx001e101f0000"
```

So the problem is solved.